# Retrieve database result and assign it to a string in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the below table at my sql server.

Table name- userinfo

```
Name    Company_id    Task1   Task2    Task3  
Anna     123           TRUE   TRUE     FALSE
Neeva    456           FALSE  TRUE     FALSE
```

I need to know the user task1, task2 and task3 status. for e.g. Anna has true for Task1 and Task2. So i need below output.

Annas details as a string --> (task1, task2)
Similarly for neeva --> (task2)

Now by using this sql query,

```
SELECT case WHEN ( SUBSTRING (value, LEN(value), 1) = ',') THEN
SUBSTRING (value, 1, (LEN(value) -1) )
ELSE
value END from (
select 
(CASE WHEN Task1 = 1 THEN 'Task1,' ELSE ''END) + 

(CASE WHEN Task2 = 1 THEN 'Task2,' ELSE ''END)  +  

(CASE WHEN Task3 = 1 THEN 'Task3,' ELSE ''END) value

from userinfo tab
```

I get the following result in SQL with a new column.

```
(No column name)
task1,task2
task1
```

Instead of creating a new column with the output i needed, i need to pass this output to C#. For e.g. if i want to know the status of Anna, i will query the database and check for user Anna first. Once done, i will check the status.

So at the C# side, i need to get something like this

```
string userdetails = task1,task2
```

This details should show up only when i queried for user anna). How can i get result in c# instead of displaying the result in SQL column as shown above.

Comment: Read about Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in c# after you have retrieved the raw data for a specific user from the database.  Here is a console app of how to approach your issue:

Create a POCO to hold you user info

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool Task1 { get; set; }
    public bool Task2 { get; set; }
    public bool Task3 { get; set; }
}
```

Create a variable to hold the Test data

```
static List<UserInfo> _userInfo;
```

Then a method to hydrate the variable

```
private static void CreateMockData()
    {
        _userInfo = new List<UserInfo>();

        _userInfo.Add(new UserInfo { Name = "Anna", CompanyId = "123", Task1 = true, Task2 = true, Task3 = false });
        _userInfo.Add(new UserInfo { Name = "Neeva", CompanyId = "456", Task1 = false, Task2 = true, Task3 = false });
    }
```

The important work will be done in another method which will examine the value of your objects and return the appropriate string

```
private static string GetUserInfoByName(string name)
    {
        StringBuilder tasks = new StringBuilder();

        // THIS WOULD BE A CALL TO THE DB TO RETURN THE RAW VALUES FOR A USER
        var userInfo = _userInfo.Find(e => e.Name == name);

        // TEST FOR TASKS HAVING THE VALUE OF TRUE
        if(userInfo.Task1)
        {
            tasks.Append("Task1,");
        }

        if(userInfo.Task2)
        {
            tasks.Append("Task2,");
        }

        if(userInfo.Task3)
        {
            tasks.Append("Task3");
        }

        // CONVERT STRING BUILDER TO A STRING
        var result = tasks.ToString();

        // REMOVE THE LAST COMMA IF WE HAVE ONE
        if(result.EndsWith(","))
        {
            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Here is the Main method that puts everything together

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // THIS DATA WOULD BE IN YOUR DATABASE
        CreateMockData();

        var userDetails = GetUserInfoByName("Anna");
        Console.WriteLine(userDetails);

        userDetails = GetUserInfoByName("Neeva");
        Console.WriteLine(userDetails);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output

Task1,Task2

Task2

Comment: Thank you so much victor for the clear explaination and a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Don't do string queries as it makes your code target for many sql injections unless you implement quite complex string escaping.

When working with C# you have multiple options.

Check out [**Entity Framework**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386876(v=vs.100).aspx) or [**Linq2Sql**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398(v=vs.110).aspx)

I personally prefer the second because it's more suitable for very modular needs when you're building queries on interfaces (with some restrictions) where EF cannot compile due to missing mappings.